# thread level memory consumption of process

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, procfs

How do I get per thread based memory consumption of a process in Linux?
I understand that we can use /proc/pid/task/tid/statm, but thats not helping my case.
All the threads show same value and its same as PID's statm.

We can do valgrind but I am not looking for any invalid read/write or leaks. 
Valgrind will not tell me any thread level info.

Any other suggestions?

EDIT:
How do I profile my code? How much memory was allocated in which function/line number etc.?

Comment: Well, conceptually, all threads have access to the same pool of memory, so they all use the same amount. What you want to track is the number of allocations per thread--and I don't think glibc or the kernel does that.  And consider: how do you count a block of memory that's allocated in one thread, and freed in another?

Comment: I can write wrapper above malloc which can collect stats but its difficult if I am profiling huge code with plenty of malloc.

Comment: How about using a wrapper around malloc that calls `gettid(2)`?  That way, you could keep the calling code the same while keeping track of which thread is calling the wrapper.

Comment: I could pass some variable in malloc wrapper to keep track of thread as well. This number remain same even if tid changes across multiple execution. But thats not an issue. 

Real issue is that one has to maintain global stat variables across threads with mutex etc. My code is quite huge and replacing all this malloc would be difficult. But thats the only viable option it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the threads share the same address space and use the same heap, so except for their stack, they should all show the same memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me rephrase my question then:
How do I profile my binaries at thread level? I mean, how much memory was allocated at what point in code?

My threads are typically not sharing memory blocks. They just share some fds, IPC files etc.

Comment: accepting this as thats the only answer I got anyway :D

I agree with the fact that its showing same mem usage. Couldn't do much beyond that..

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Linux to see the thread level usage of cpu and memory

You can use command `top` with option `-H` and `-p`

```
top -H -p<PID>
```

Command will list the result with following header and you should read `PID` as TID(Thread id) in this case.

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND`
```

In case of java process it is quite obvious as follows. If you create a thread dump of a process and convert the thread id to decimal you can match with the TID listed in output of `top -H -p <PID>`

For